# Prove there is no bounded function $\rho\in \mathcal{R}$ on $[-1,1]$ such that $\int_{-1}^1 f(x)\rho(x) dx=f(0)$ for every continuous $f$ on $[-1,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, solution-verification, riemann-integration

> Prove there is no bounded function $\rho\in \mathcal{R}$ on $[-1,1]$ such that $\int_{-1}^1 f(x)\rho(x) dx=f(0)$ for every continuous $f$ on $[-1,1]$.

My attempt so far:

> First, this Riemann integral makes sense since $f$ is continuous on a closed interval, and if $f,g\in \mathcal{R}$, $fg\in \mathcal{R}$.
>
> Suppose there exists such $\rho\in \mathcal{R}$ on $[-1,1]$. Then, by assumption, we have
>
> $|\int_{-1}^1 f(x)\rho(x) dx-f(0)|<\epsilon$
>
> So,
>
> $f(0)-\epsilon<L(P,f\rho) \leq|\int_{-1}^1 f(x)\rho(x) dx-f(0)|\leq U(P,f\rho)<f(0)+\epsilon$
>
> Consider $U(P,f\rho)<f(0)+\epsilon$. Let $P=${$x_0,...,x_{j-1},x_j,...,x_n$} where $x_{j-1}\leq 0< x_j$. WLOG, further suppose this $P$ doesn't contain any duplicates.
>
> $U(P,f\rho)=\sum_{i=1}^n M_{fi}M_{\rho i}\Delta x_i<f(0)+\epsilon$

I have no idea how to proceed and I don't even know if I'm on the right track.

Comment: The most important point in the proof is the choice of $f$. You are working with a general $f$ and that doesn't help at all.

Comment: Are you allowed to use Dominated Convergence Theorem?

Comment: IF you take $f=1$, it follows that $\int_{-1}^1\rho(x)dx=1$.

Comment: @geetha290krm No, I haven't learnt such theorem.

Comment: @TitoEliatron I still don't get what you mean. Can you elaborate your idea, please?

Comment: It is just a comment that may or may not helps

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $f_n(x)=1-n|x|$ for $ |x| \leq \frac  1n$ and $0$ for $|x| >\frac  1 n$. This function is continuous and the hypothesis gives $\int_{-1/n}^{1/n}(1-n|x|)\rho(x)dx=1$. Hence, $1 \leq \int_{-1/n}^{1/n}|\rho(x)|dx$. This is true for every $n$.  Now get a contradiction by showing that $\int_{-1/n}^{1/n}|\rho(x)|dx \to 0$ as $ n \to \infty$.

Comment: Very elegant proof

Comment: Does this function $f_n$ take $0$ for $x<0$?

Comment: I mistook the domain to be $[0,1]$ instead of $[-1,1]$. I have now corrected my proof.

Comment: @friendOfMath $0\leq 1-n|x| \leq 1$ for $|x|\leq \frac1  n$.

Comment: Yes, you got it right. @friendOfMath